# Consequence of student debt forgiveness

Tags: reference-request, debt

US government has recently announced student debt forgiveness plan ([link](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2022/08/24/fact-sheet-president-biden-announces-student-loan-relief-for-borrowers-who-need-it-most/)). What are the consequences of student debt forgiveness that is discussed in the economics literature, encompassing its effects on:

- individuals with student debt;
- its general equilibrium effects on the economy?

My instinct is that this plan is inflationary, since it increases government spending, and also increases disposable income for students with student loan. Will this student debt forgiveness be any different than a lump-sum transfer to these individuals? Listing any paper that surveys the effects of student debt forgiveness would be great!